# How can I get a method to print?

Tags: java

I wanted to make a really simple program for a calendar in text. This is the first time I tried to print a method, I can't figure out how to do it.

```
public class Calendar{
public static void main(String[] args){
System.out.println("January: ");
System.out.println("S   M   T   W   TH  F   S");
}
public static void displayMonth(int i){
for (i = 1; i < 32; i++){
    if (i < 10){
        System.out.print(i + "   ");
    }else{
        System.out.print(i + "  ");
    }
    if (i % 7 == 0 ){
    System.out.print("\n"); 
            }
         }
    }
}
```

That is the code. How do I get "displayMonth to appear?

Comment: You need to invoke method displayMonth

Comment: In your main method, run the method. Like this: `displayMonth(0)`. And, why do you have an int parameter? Just do `int i` in the for-loop. And you need to read up on the basics.

Comment: Can you explain your logic.It seems to be completely wrong

Comment: Are you going through a Java tutorial or lesson book? If not, please have a look here: [The Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html). You won't regret the effort.

Answer (score 2):

Add `displayMonth(1)` to the bottom of `main` function.

Also, find a good Java tutorial.

p.s. you are ignoring the argument to the function, by setting it to 1.

Answer (score 1):

just call the method in your main method where you have printed January and days name by writing displayMonth(1),
Or call it in your constructor and write this in your main method. You can do it like this,

```
//This is Constructor and this should be written within your class
public Calender(){
    System.out.println("January: ");
    System.out.println("S   M   T   W   TH  F   S");
    displayMonth(1)
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    new Calender();
}
```